# Cordova ios back button issue

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, back

We have developed a mobile application in cordova, after undergoing the application on Apple store 20 days again later, we received a communication in which Apple refuses to submit our application for the following reasons:

Reasons :

10.6: Apple and our customers place a high value on simple, refined, creative, well thought through interfaces. They take more work but are worth it. Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface is complex or less than very good, it may be rejected
----- 10.6 -----

We found the following issues with the user interface of your app:

Specifically, there were no back buttons on social media web views displayed in the app. In order to return to the main app from a community page, such as Facebook or Twitter, the app had to be closed and re-launched.

These examples identify types of issues discovered in your app but may not represent all such issues. It would be appropriate to thoroughly evaluate your app to address these types of issues.

---

In fact we use links to our pages on social networks, it works well on Android, because it simply click the back button to return the phone. Thing that is not obvious on an iPhone.

Is there a method to solve this? A webview? a popup with a close button ? an HTML5 iframe ?

THANK YOU !

Answer (score 0):

You can use official [InAppBrowser](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser) plugin (it should have a close button x), or just open these links externally in browser (safari).

In addition, IMHO, you are risking to lose your precious users by opening social links on top of your (or inside) your own app. People can get distracted and just browse away.

Comment: I'll try this point. Thank you so much @mentat for your tips !